# Can't connect to Oracle database with SQL developer, SQL*Plus is working fine

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, oracle12c

When I call `net start OracleServiceORCL` on the Windows command line I get

> The requested service has already been started.

When I then run `sqlplus` on the command line I can log on to my database successfully.

However when using SQL Developer to connect to the database with the same credentials I'm getting the error

> I/O error: The network adapter could not establish the connection.
>
> Vendor code: 17002

The same error occurs when I starting my application server which is connected to the database.

I was already able to use SQL developer or start my server but don't know of anything that has changed since then. How can I make it work again?

Comment: Some of the things which needs to be looked into are: port to connect, service name to connect. Because, 12c uses service name to connect to PDB instead of service ID.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a lot of reasons for these. You can start checking your listener status. Check if Oracle listener is running for your database. sqlplus can connect to your database even if the listener is stopped, i'm not sure how it does. But with the listener not running it will disable the clients like sqldeveloper even it is on the same machine to locate your database.

```
> lsnrctl services
```

Answer (score 0):

What sort of connection are you using? Oracle clients can use two types of connection via TCP or bequeath connection.

When using sqlplus on the same host as your DB is running, you usually do `sqlplus / as sysdba` this will create connection using bequeauth. Bequeauth bypasses the listener completely and directly spawns a child process which will handle requests to DB.

If you use sqlplus like this `sqlplus username@host` you are connecting using TCP via listener, which handles the connection and spawns process that will communicate with the DB.

Oracle listener by default runs on port 1521 so my first guess if the listener is running is that firewall is blocking access to 1521.

You should try to connect to db using first bequeatuh then via listener, if bequeauth works and TCP connection doesn't the problem is probably somewhere between listener and network. (You can also setup sqldeveloper to use bequeauth but it has to be installed on the same host as DB)

You can check listener status using `lsnrctl status` if everything seems fine there check the file listed under *Listener Log File* to see if any connections are being made via listener, or if there are any errors present.